# create a dynamic select list with a default value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wan't to create a dynamic drop down menue, with default selected values. Creating from the dropdown menu works fine, but when I set the default value, that isn't working. The default value was set only for the last dropdown. I have to create a example:

```js
let brand = [{
    "brand": "audi"
  },
  {
    "brand": "mercedes"
  }

]
$(document).ready(function() {
  createTableBody()
})

function createTableBody() {
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var row = `<tr>
                    <td>${i}</td>
                    <td><select class="brand" id="brand${i}"><option value="">brand</option></select></th>
               </tr>`
    table.innerHTML += row
    createDropdown(brand, i)
  }
}

function createDropdown(data, x) {
  var selectList = document.getElementById('brand' + x)
  //create and insert from the option element
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option")
    option.value = data[i].brand
    option.text = data[i].brand
    selectList.appendChild(option)
  }
  console.log(selectList)
  selectList.value = "mercedes"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-column="id" data-order="desc">ID</th>
      <th data-column="brand" data-order="desc">Brand</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="pabBody">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to choose the default `mercedes` for everyone?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov yes exactly

Comment: @KlausM. I think the problem is with `table.innerHTML += row`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with

```
table.innerHTML += row;
```

this is the same as

```
table.innerHTML = table.innerHTML + row;
```

and taking the `.innerHTML` of an element takes *only* the HTML, not the currently selected values.

You can fix this by *appending* HTML rather than *replacing* the HTML, eg (as tagged jquery)

```
$(table).append(row);
```

this will leave all the existing selected values as they are as they are not being replaced.

```js
let brand = [{
    "brand": "audi"
  },
  {
    "brand": "mercedes"
  }

]
$(document).ready(function() {
  createTableBody()
})

function createTableBody() {
  //var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
  var table = $("#myTable");
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var row = `<tr>
                    <td>${i}</td>
                    <td><select class="brand" id="brand${i}"><option value="">brand</option></select></th>
               </tr>`
    //table.innerHTML += row
    table.append(row);
    createDropdown(brand, i)
  }
}

function createDropdown(data, x) {
  var selectList = document.getElementById('brand' + x)
  //create and insert from the option element
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option")
    option.value = data[i].brand
    option.text = data[i].brand
    selectList.appendChild(option)
  }
  console.log(selectList)
  selectList.value = "mercedes"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-column="id" data-order="desc">ID</th>
      <th data-column="brand" data-order="desc">Brand</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="pabBody">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

An alternative would be to build your select `option`s at the same time as you build your `select`.  Or build all your HTML in the same way you build your select options (`document.createElement("tr")` etc)

Comment: thanks for the detailed explenation my friend. This solve my Problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
function createTableBody() {
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var row = `<tr>
                    <td>${i}</td>
                    <td><select class="brand" id="brand${i}"><option value="">brand</option></select></th>
               </tr>`
    table.innerHTML += row
  }
  createDropdown()
}

function createDropdown() {
  var selectList = document.querySelectorAll('select[id^=brand]')
  //create and insert from the option element
  for (var j = 0; j < selectList.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < brand.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option")
      option.value = brand[i].brand
      option.text = brand[i].brand
      selectList[j].appendChild(option)
    }
    selectList[j].value = "mercedes"
  }
  console.log(selectList)
}
```

I believe the problem was that you updated the innerhtml multiple times, so I think it was resetting the selected values of the past selects

**Demo**

```js
let brand = [{
    "brand": "audi"
  },
  {
    "brand": "mercedes"
  }

]
$(document).ready(function() {
  createTableBody()
})

function createTableBody() {
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var row = `<tr>
                    <td>${i}</td>
                    <td><select class="brand" id="brand${i}"><option value="">brand</option></select></th>
               </tr>`
    table.innerHTML += row
  }
  createDropdown()
}

function createDropdown() {
  var selectList = document.querySelectorAll('select[id^=brand]')
  //create and insert from the option element
  for (var j = 0; j < selectList.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < brand.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option")
      option.value = brand[i].brand
      option.text = brand[i].brand
      selectList[j].appendChild(option)
    }
    selectList[j].value = "mercedes"
  }
  console.log(selectList)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-column="id" data-order="desc">ID</th>
      <th data-column="brand" data-order="desc">Brand</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="pabBody">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

When all select elements are added to DOM set default value to `mercedes`.

Just add line of code

`$('.brand').val('mercedes');`

after `createTableBody()`

OR

I modified your code to a more efficient one.

```js
let brand = [{
    "brand": "audi"
  },
  {
    "brand": "mercedes"
  }

]
$(document).ready(function() {
  createTableBody();
})

function createTableBody() {
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   const selectStr = `<tr>
                      <td>${i}<td>
                      <td>
                      <select class='brand' id='brand${i}'>
                        <option value=''>Please select ....</option>
                        ${brand.map(x => `<option value=${x.brand} ${x.brand === 'mercedes' ? 'selected' : null}>${x.brand}</option>`)}
                     </select>
                     </td>
                     </tr>`;

   table.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",selectStr);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-column="id" data-order="desc">ID</th>
      <th data-column="brand" data-order="desc">Brand</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="pabBody">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Check my updated answer it's a smaller solution to your problem.